# Problem inserting template below add to cart with rwd theme

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, addtocart, rwd-theme

I have a template and I inserting it in the product view page. I want to show my template (it is a table) below the add to cart button. It works with the default theme but when I use the rwd theme it puts my template inside a div with a class `add-to-cart-buttons` and then my template modifies the size of the add-to-cart button (that is also inside this div).

I want to show my template below add to cart button but whitout corrupt the add to cart button size.

This is my xml:

```
<catalog_product_view>        
    <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block type="core/template" name="my.table" template="my/path/table.phtml" after="-"/>            
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

And this is the add to cart button (named Adicionar ao Carrinho because of my translation) bigger than usual:

[image: add to carc bigger than usual]

I think the problem here is because of the template had been inserted inside the same div of the add-to-cart button, but I don't know why with rwd theme this happens. Anyone  could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring the layout block `product.info.addtocart` Means, that will be added to the template `catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Try below:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="my.table" template="my/path/table.phtml" after="product.info.addtocart"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Did not work., my template not appeared. And the problem is not to be in the addtocart block, the problem is that it is inserted inside the div where the button is placed, instead of only be in the addtocart block, like in the default theme.